# Show taxonomy term's image field on node page

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms

Ive added an image field to my taxonomy terms. On a node I need to display the image of the terms it tagged with.

Ive created a view with the NID as an argument and attached it to the node content type with the EVA module.

Ive added a relationship of 'Taxonomy terms on node'. This allows me to add 'Content: All taxonomy terms' as a field which shows the term name, but I cant figure out how to load the term's image instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this in a different way, using Display Suite module you can simply render taxonomy terms in a desired view mode.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I was hoping to achieve this without installing any new major modules.